# Django Channels and Django Rest Framework integration

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I´m trying to build a real-time backend for a multiplayer mobile game with Django.

I want to know if someone has worked in a similar project using Django Channels and DRF, or if there has been some progress in the [official integration](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/mozilla-grant/#realtime-apis), which I am not able to find.

Thanks in advance for any info!

Answer (score -1):

Our project is using both DRF and django-channels. So far they have been  very flexible and intuitive frameworks to work with. In terms of online material there is much more available in terms of DRF than channels, but both frameworks have excellent documentation. We started our application by integrating channels before DRF. If you are using asynchronous channels code to read or write to your database, make sure you look at the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html) regarding the process

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the info. I've worked with both frameworks separately and I found both really useful and with very good documentation, but when trying to integrate them I have no idea where to start. I was looking for some online tutorial about the integration or some open-source project to review.

Comment: Good luck finding exactly what you are trying to build. If I were you I would consider breaking the problem into smaller parts instead of copying and pasting a bunch of code written by someone else you don't understand.

Comment: I'm just asking for an example, or tutorial. I don't see why I wouldn't understand the code, but thanks anyway